# invalid json stored in db

Tags: json, validation, parsing

I previously retrived some data and stored it in my database as such:

```
{'data': {'housingMarket': [{'actual': {'transactions': 737, 'avgSoldPrice': 796611, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 573, 'avgSoldPrice': 874925}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 157, 'avgSoldPrice': 700215}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 87, 'avgSoldPrice': 480947}}}, 'timestamp': 1630472400000, 'date': '2021-09-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 766, 'avgSoldPrice': 779486, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 516, 'avgSoldPrice': 854825}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 138, 'avgSoldPrice': 687630}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 84, 'avgSoldPrice': 489423}}}, 'timestamp': 1627794000000, 'date': '2021-08-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 782, 'avgSoldPrice': 779783, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 534, 'avgSoldPrice': 845840}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 153, 'avgSoldPrice': 694160}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 84, 'avgSoldPrice': 472675}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 882500}, 'timestamp': 1625115600000, 'date': '2021-07-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 966, 'avgSoldPrice': 787758, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 687, 'avgSoldPrice': 870289}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 212, 'avgSoldPrice': 675337}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 116, 'avgSoldPrice': 448882}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 879100}, 'timestamp': 1622523600000, 'date': '2021-06-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 1137, 'avgSoldPrice': 792746, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 851, 'avgSoldPrice': 860953}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 260, 'avgSoldPrice': 667672}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 101, 'avgSoldPrice': 480790}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 879100}, 'timestamp': 1619845200000, 'date': '2021-05-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 1195, 'avgSoldPrice': 786737, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 1030, 'avgSoldPrice': 857201}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 312, 'avgSoldPrice': 679626}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 121, 'avgSoldPrice': 466264}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 866900}, 'timestamp': 1617253200000, 'date': '2021-04-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 1302, 'avgSoldPrice': 804223, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 993, 'avgSoldPrice': 874766}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 318, 'avgSoldPrice': 693250}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 131, 'avgSoldPrice': 462888}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 865300}, 'timestamp': 1614574800000, 'date': '2021-03-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 745, 'avgSoldPrice': 769774, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 567, 'avgSoldPrice': 843374}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 206, 'avgSoldPrice': 684362}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 76, 'avgSoldPrice': 439221}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 833100}, 'timestamp': 1612155600000, 'date': '2021-02-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 486, 'avgSoldPrice': 722628, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 352, 'avgSoldPrice': 798431}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 105, 'avgSoldPrice': 607516}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 74, 'avgSoldPrice': 413664}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 784600}, 'timestamp': 1609477200000, 'date': '2021-01-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 577, 'avgSoldPrice': 661783, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 262, 'avgSoldPrice': 723458}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 78, 'avgSoldPrice': 577106}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 44, 'avgSoldPrice': 401569}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 756000}, 'timestamp': 1606798800000, 'date': '2020-12-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 779, 'avgSoldPrice': 651744, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 515, 'avgSoldPrice': 721064}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 151, 'avgSoldPrice': 555619}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 83, 'avgSoldPrice': 365971}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 735300}, 'timestamp': 1604203200000, 'date': '2020-11-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 983, 'avgSoldPrice': 662511, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 666, 'avgSoldPrice': 726515}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 199, 'avgSoldPrice': 558208}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 97, 'avgSoldPrice': 393780}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 727100}, 'timestamp': 1601524800000, 'date': '2020-10-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 1065, 'avgSoldPrice': 664330, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 756, 'avgSoldPrice': 733989}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 219, 'avgSoldPrice': 559502}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 100, 'avgSoldPrice': 377431}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 718600}, 'timestamp': 1598932800000, 'date': '2020-09-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 865, 'avgSoldPrice': 662257, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 741, 'avgSoldPrice': 735318}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 221, 'avgSoldPrice': 560518}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 111, 'avgSoldPrice': 379706}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 702600}, 'timestamp': 1596254400000, 'date': '2020-08-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 1026, 'avgSoldPrice': 628834, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 818, 'avgSoldPrice': 696849}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 248, 'avgSoldPrice': 554614}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 111, 'avgSoldPrice': 377004}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 687000}, 'timestamp': 1593576000000, 'date': '2020-07-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 825, 'avgSoldPrice': 619049, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 770, 'avgSoldPrice': 677065}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 207, 'avgSoldPrice': 523466}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 127, 'avgSoldPrice': 340106}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 674600}, 'timestamp': 1590984000000, 'date': '2020-06-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 574, 'avgSoldPrice': 604578, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 505, 'avgSoldPrice': 667694}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 132, 'avgSoldPrice': 538623}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 91, 'avgSoldPrice': 380026}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 659800}, 'timestamp': 1588305600000, 'date': '2020-05-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 341, 'avgSoldPrice': 555543, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 379, 'avgSoldPrice': 600258}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 127, 'avgSoldPrice': 504043}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 57, 'avgSoldPrice': 364070}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 652100}, 'timestamp': 1585713600000, 'date': '2020-04-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 723, 'avgSoldPrice': 605140, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 727, 'avgSoldPrice': 663767}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 209, 'avgSoldPrice': 528215}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 87, 'avgSoldPrice': 375366}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 653200}, 'timestamp': 1583038800000, 'date': '2020-03-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 664, 'avgSoldPrice': 588817, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 620, 'avgSoldPrice': 637246}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 153, 'avgSoldPrice': 539195}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 83, 'avgSoldPrice': 346250}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 641100}, 'timestamp': 1580533200000, 'date': '2020-02-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 485, 'avgSoldPrice': 562235, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 511, 'avgSoldPrice': 603457}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 117, 'avgSoldPrice': 506941}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 69, 'avgSoldPrice': 378974}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 629800}, 'timestamp': 1577854800000, 'date': '2020-01-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 425, 'avgSoldPrice': 531283, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 225, 'avgSoldPrice': 573204}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 56, 'avgSoldPrice': 480825}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 34, 'avgSoldPrice': 334736}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 622100}, 'timestamp': 1575176400000, 'date': '2019-12-01T17:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 643, 'avgSoldPrice': 535944, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 523, 'avgSoldPrice': 575284}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 97, 'avgSoldPrice': 477738}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 63, 'avgSoldPrice': 325391}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 627100}, 'timestamp': 1572580800000, 'date': '2019-11-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 752, 'avgSoldPrice': 544980, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 803, 'avgSoldPrice': 593796}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 176, 'avgSoldPrice': 472826}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 75, 'avgSoldPrice': 347635}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 623500}, 'timestamp': 1569902400000, 'date': '2019-10-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}, {'actual': {'transactions': 692, 'avgSoldPrice': 545902, 'breakdown': {'detached': {'newListings': 907, 'avgSoldPrice': 599584}, 'semiDetached': {'newListings': 238, 'avgSoldPrice': 458965}, 'apartment': {'newListings': 75, 'avgSoldPrice': 322247}}, 'benchmarkPrice': 617900}, 'timestamp': 1567310400000, 'date': '2019-09-01T16:00:00.000Z', '__typename': 'RealEstateData'}]}}
```

However, when I parse the above data thru and validator, such as https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer , I am met with this error

```
Parse error on line 1:
{'data': {'housingMar
-^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: JSON requires double quotes. Is the question "how do I fix it?"? If so please edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: That looks like the string representation of a Python dictionary. After you load a valid JSON document, are you storing the dictionary string directly in the dictionary, without converting it back to a valid JSON syntax? We need more details: language used and example code to load and store the JSON data.